Salt & hand sanitizer
When you mix salt and hand-sanitizer; the hand-sanitizer becomes more of a liquid. Can you explain chemically why?
Thoughts:
I’m assuming some reaction between the salt and in the hand sanitizer. I don’t believe the hand sanitizer necessarily heats up. Could it be a separation between the gel and alcohol ingredients in the hand-sanitizer that was caused by a reaction with the salt?

When you mix salt with hand sanitizer containing ethanol (alcohol) as the primary solvent, the salt disrupts the polymeric thickener's ability to maintain viscosity(sanitizers have ethanol + polymeric thickener + preservatives/perfumes). As a result, the thickener separates out, forming a dense plug of water and gel at the bottom while mostly pure ethanol remains floating on top. This separation and disruption of the thickening agent cause the hand sanitizer to become more liquid-like.
